# Ingress NGINX for autoreview apps (gitlab-managed-apps) very slow if large json posted

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, nginx-ingress

i'm experiencing a strange behavior of Ingress-Nginx if i post payloads bigger than 50k. If so, the forwarding time of the submitted post-request in Nginx takes up to 50 seconds or more, but if i submit smaller a smaller load, Nginx forwards very speedy. If i post a 4mb request, it takes up to 100 seconds.

Environemnt:
- Baremetall kubernetes cluster with 3 nodes with Ubuntu 16.04
- deployment over custom helm templates out of gitlab
- gitlab-managed Nginx-controller pod, proxy routing over host header
- java application receiving post and returns it

Application topology:
web -> (apache reverse proxy) -> (IngressNginx) -> (Application)
i can see that apache forwards the whole payload straight forward and Nginx pod receives it immediately, but the application pod does not receive anything for up to 50 seconds (depends on payload size), sometimes i also run into a Nginx 502, but i cant find a pattern.

I've tried higher or lower down buffer sizes, disabled or enabled buffering, but without any effects:

```
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "5M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "5M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: "1"
```

`ingress.yaml` template:

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "integrity-adapter-autodeployment.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.service.port -}}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "integrity-adapter-autodeployment.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "100M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: "5M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "300"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-buffer-size: "5M"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-next-upstream-tries: "1"
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ $svcPort }}
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

`nginx.conf` only for this server:

````
    ## start server feature-document-response-integrity-adapter.prod.semanticlab.net
    server {
        server_name feature-document-response-integrity-adapter.prod.semanticlab.net ;

        listen 80  ;
        listen 443  ssl http2 ;

        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
            certificate.call()
        }

        location ~* "^/" {

            set $namespace      "default";
            set $ingress_name   "review-integrity-adapter-feature-document-response";
            set $service_name   "review-integrity-adapter-feature-document-response";
            set $service_port   "63016";
            set $location_path  "/";

            rewrite_by_lua_block {
                lua_ingress.rewrite({
                    force_ssl_redirect = false,
                    ssl_redirect = true,
                    force_no_ssl_redirect = false,
                    use_port_in_redirects = false,
                })
                balancer.rewrite()
                plugins.run()
            }

            # be careful with `access_by_lua_block` and `satisfy any` directives as satisfy any
            # will always succeed when there's `access_by_lua_block` that does not have any lua code doing `ngx.exit(ngx.DECLINED)`
            # other authentication method such as basic auth or external auth useless - all requests will be allowed.
            #access_by_lua_block {
            #}

            header_filter_by_lua_block {
                lua_ingress.header()
                plugins.run()
            }

            body_filter_by_lua_block {
            }

            log_by_lua_block {
                balancer.log()

                monitor.call()

                plugins.run()
            }

            port_in_redirect off;

            set $balancer_ewma_score -1;
            set $proxy_upstream_name "default-review-integrity-adapter-feature-document-response-63016";
            set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;
            set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;

            set $pass_server_port    $server_port;

            set $best_http_host      $http_host;
            set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;

            set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";

            client_max_body_size                    100M;

            client_body_buffer_size                 5M;

            proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers to proxied server

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      300s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

            proxy_buffering                         on;
            proxy_buffer_size                       5M;
            proxy_buffers                           4 5M;

            proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;

            proxy_request_buffering                 on;
            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
            proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
            proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries               1;

            proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

            proxy_redirect                          off;

        }

    }
    ## end server feature-document-response-integrity-adapter.prod.semanticlab.net
    ```

Does some have any suggestions for me?
Thanks in advance
````

Comment: This kind of question is best to be asked to nginx ingress developers directly on [nginx ingress guthub repo](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues).

Answer (score 0):

After a week of searching the issue, we finally found it... Ingress-Nginx has gzip compression active by default. Creating a configMap with `use-gzip: "false"` fixed the issue.

`kubectl apply -f {configmap.yaml}`

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
 use-gzip: "false"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx-ingress
    component: controller
    heritage: Tiller
    release: ingress
  name: ingress-nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: gitlab-managed-apps
```